# Cropping image after resizing or moving of cropping rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have implemented a Crop User Control for my program and I want to add moveable and resizable functionality. I'm currently following Sukrahms Diagram Designer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1. But since my rectangle is not created not until the user drags and makes a rectangle I'm getting unexpected result. Right Now I'm just trying to create a rectangle that is contained inside a ContentControl but when i drag the mouse to create a rectangle it starst at the very left edge of the window and not at the location where I clicked the mouseleftbuttondown. Below are my codes.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Klein_Tools_Profile_Pic_Generator.CropControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Klein_Tools_Profile_Pic_Generator"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MoveThumbTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type s:MoveThumb}">
        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- ResizeDecorator Template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizeDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid>
            <s:ResizeThumb Height="3" Cursor="SizeNS" Margin="0 -4 0 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="3" Cursor="SizeWE" Margin="-4 0 0 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="3" Cursor="SizeWE" Margin="0 0 -4 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Height="3" Cursor="SizeNS" Margin="0 0 0 -4"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="7" Height="7" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Margin="-6 -6 0 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="7" Height="7" Cursor="SizeNESW" Margin="0 -6 -6 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="7" Height="7" Cursor="SizeNESW" Margin="-6 0 0 -6"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="7" Height="7" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Margin="0 0 -6 -6"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- Designer Item Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" Cursor="SizeAll"/>
            <Control Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Canvas x:Name="BackPanel"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
        MouseMove="LoadedImage_MouseMove" 
        MouseLeftButtonUp="LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonUp"
        Background="Transparent">
    <ContentControl x:Name="contControl" Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
        <Rectangle x:Name="selectionRectangle" Fill="#220000FF"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

User Control CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Klein_Tools_Profile_Pic_Generator
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CropControl.xaml
/// </summary>

public partial class CropControl : UserControl
{
    private bool isDragging = false;
    private Point anchorPoint = new Point();
    public CropControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    //Register the Dependency Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Selection", typeof(Rect), typeof(CropControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Rect)));

    public Rect Selection
    {
        get { return (Rect)GetValue(SelectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectionProperty, value); }
    }

    // this is used, to react on changes from ViewModel. If you assign a  
    // new Rect in your ViewModel you will have to redraw your Rect here
    private static void OnSelectionChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rect newRect = (Rect)e.NewValue;
        Rectangle selectionRectangle = d as Rectangle;

        if (selectionRectangle != null)
            return;

        selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newRect.X);
        selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newRect.Y);
        selectionRectangle.Width = newRect.Width;
        selectionRectangle.Height = newRect.Height;
    }

    private void LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging == false)
        {
            anchorPoint.X = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).X;
            anchorPoint.Y = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).Y;
            Canvas.SetZIndex(selectionRectangle, 999);
            isDragging = true;
            BackPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }

    }

    private void LoadedImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            double x = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).X;
            double y = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).Y;
            contControl.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Math.Min(x, anchorPoint.X));
            contControl.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Math.Min(y, anchorPoint.Y));
            contControl.Width = Math.Abs(x - anchorPoint.X);
            contControl.Height = Math.Abs(y - anchorPoint.Y);

             if (contControl.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
                contControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            if (contControl.Width > 0)
            {
                //Crop.IsEnabled = true;
                //Cut.IsEnabled = true;
                BackPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }

            contControl.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
            // Set the Selection to the new rect, when the mouse button has been released
            Selection = new Rect(
                (double)contControl.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty),
                (double)contControl.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty),
                contControl.Width,
                contControl.Height);

        }
    }

}
```

}

I'm thinking I would need to retrieve the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Bottom from Rectangle by binding it to my ContentControl but I dont know how. I looked everywhere and I cant come up with anything. How should i retrieve this attached properties or are there better ways of implementing a moveable and resizable cropping rectangle?

**Update:**

I did some adjustment with my code followin Toby's advice and now the crop rectangle moves and resizes as expected. Initially after the user drags the mouse and create the rectangle it crops as normal, but when I move or resize the same rectangle it doesn't crop. I would need some way to change the dimension and X/Y value of the rectangle in my codebehind if it gets moved or resized but I'm not sure how to implement this. Any advise would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be the related to the Rectangle being embedded in a ContentControl.  Try the following:

```
<Canvas x:Name="BackPanel" MouseLeftButtonDown="LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="LoadedImage_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonUp" Background="Transparent">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Rectangle x:Name="selectionRectangle" Stroke="LightBlue" Fill="#220000FF" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Canvas>
```

When the Rectangle is not on the canvas, but rather in a ContentControl which is on the Canvas:

```
selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Math.Min(x, anchorPoint.X));
selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Math.Min(y, anchorPoint.Y));
```

These attached properties appear not to work as you intend.
If you need the Rectangle to be in a ContentControl, you can set the attached properties on the ContentControl itself (which is a child on the Canvas)

```
contentControl.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Math.Min(x, anchorPoint.X));
contentControl.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Math.Min(y, anchorPoint.Y));
```

Comment: @ Toby Crawford Thanks, Your later advise work where the rectangle is contained inside content control. As stated in my update after changing the code it still comes up with one problem. It does not crop after moving or resizing the rectangle.